# Need help on understanding mechanical wave function

Tags: waves, wavefunction

My textbook states that,

equation 1 : y(x=0,t) = Acos($\omega$t) = Acos(2$\pi$ft), which I understand.

However the book goes deeper stating also that,

t-$\frac{x}{v}$, and $\frac{x}{v}$-t

I am certain the first fraction is when the wave is moving to -x direction, and the opposite for the second fraction.

However, I am not really clear on what values to use for t, x, and v.

Are t and x the same values used as input, as in y(x,t)? (whatever the value that goes into function as inputs?

Also then, why bother using fractions?

Okay, I think I got it... Use fractions because above equation is only valid for when calculating the motion of a particle at the left end of the string..

Comment: At the end of the day, do you have an actual question - or did you just need to think out loud? These expressions you wrote: $t - \frac{x}{v}$ and $\frac{v}{x} - t$ don't make sense: at least one of them is dimensionally nonsensical ($\frac{v}{x}$ has dimensions of $\frac{1}{t}$ not $t$. And it is unclear what you intend these expressions to represent.

Comment: Apparently, being a noob at mathjax, I have wrongly placed different symbols. It should be read as I have just editted.

Answer (score 0):

As previously stated, one of your expressions is dimensionally inconsistent.  However, it appears that your textbook is defining the vertical displacement of your wave for every point x on the wave, not just at x=0.  This is done by noting that since x=vt, you can define a time offset from your origin by subtracting t = x/v from your original time, leading to the expression t = t0 - x/v.  Such a correction will give you a phase difference from the point x=0 to the new point x, where this phase difference will be constant if the angular frequency is constant and the properties of the medium are constant.